# ruby best way to get alternative value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Say I'm having two strings `"Cat" and "Mouse"`

I put them in an array

```
arr = ["Cat","Mouse"]
```

And I have two variables say `hero and villain`

Now the variable `hero` will be assigned dynamically which will be either "Cat" or "Mouse"

So what will be the best way to assign `villain` variable by eliminating `hero` value from `arr`

Ex

```
hero = # Either "Cat" or "Mouse"
villain = # The NOT HERO VALUE in arr
```

FYI: I know it can be done using a function or some manual tricks. But I just wonder if there is any Ruby way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
villain = (arr - [hero])[0]
```

This works well if you already know who your hero is. If you want to pick both randomly at the same time, 7stud's is better. Or this nondestructive variant:

```
hero, villain = *arr.shuffle
```

Comment: Thanks..But I was hoping for a ruby function like arr.not(hero) || arr.slice(hero)

Comment: What I wrote is almost exactly like `arr.not(hero)`: `arr.-([hero])`. Being able to write `arr - [hero]` is a syntactic sugar, really. However, the result of that is an array (`["Mouse"]`), so I apply `result[0]` (which I could also write `result.[](0)`) to just get the string. All operators in Ruby are in fact methods, it's just that they're called a bit unconventionally (`[]` and `-`, in this case). Also, using `arr.shuffle` with a splat operator (`*`) and a multiple assignment is very rubyish.

Answer (score 3):

```
arr = ["Cat","Mouse"]
arr.shuffle!

hero = arr.pop
villain = arr.pop
```

Or, you can simple write:

```
hero, villain = arr.shuffle!
```

(no splat(*) needed)

Answer (score 1):

Just to cover `sample` method:

```
arr = ["Cat","Mouse"]
hero, villain = arr.sample(2)
```